# Function s of $2 y = f *(3x - 6) - 2$

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

$2 y = f * (3x - 6) - 2$

Given this function, does it indicate a vertical expansion by 2, a horizontal expansion by 3, a translation right by 2 and a translation of 2 units down?

Comment: what do you think? beware of that $2y$ thing

Comment: what is $2y = f *( 3x - 6) - 2$? f is a constant?

Comment: @Vasya Vertical compression?

Comment: @Grimestock: Yes, exactly. It will also change your translation to 1 unit down

Comment: @Grimestock Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

For $y=f(x)$

- vertical expansion of $k \to y=kf(x)$
- horizontal expansion of $k \to y=f(x/k)$
- right translation of $k \to y=f(x-k)$
- down translation of $k \to y=f(x)-k$